# Excel Formula Clarification for Dynamic Worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dynamic Spreadsheet with three columns. Every time a record is added onto the website, it updates the worksheet. I need to calculate the `AGE` of a ticket from the `Created Date`.

I have used cell formula `=Today() - G2` in AGE column,  Where `G2` is the cell with the created date.

The column header names are:

```
Ticket Status|  Created Date | AGE
```

However I want this formula to keep adding down the rows dynamically whenever there is a new record in the list. How can I do this?

Comment: Either copy the formula down beyond your current used area, or select your data -> Insert -> Table in order to convert it to a table which will auto-fill the formula as new rows are added

Answer (score 0):

Without getting in-depth about how the website is dynamically adding data to you're sheet:

**Try:**

Modify the formula to `=IF(ISBLANK(G2),"",TODAY()-G2)` (which just keeps the cell blank if the date is empty) and then select the column and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to fill the formula down the entire column

**Other options:**

As @tigeravatar mentioned, maybe a cleaner solution would be to convert the sheet into a table.  But there are some caviates that may or may not affect you, like the sheet looking significantly different.

The cleanest solution would be to add it the the code that adds rows triggered from the website, but that may be significantly more complex.

Comment: Thanks Elijah! That first formula worked like magic! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: If you would like to accept my answer, i would be appreciative ;)

Comment: Hey I seem to be encountering issues now. Is there a way to filter and get the age? Because I have to check the age for a certain status.

Ex: Status=Progress then calculate age from created date. But there are other statuses in the table as well.

Comment: Im not sure that i fully understand, do you mean something like `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(G2),F2<>"Progress"),"",TODAY()-G2)` (Assuming column 'F' stores the status) ? This will only calculate the age is the status is equal to "Progress".